# Two questions related to Matlab Coding

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

1. How can I make code in Matlab that calculates how many storm tracks pass the line, or how many do not pass, or how many overlap with each other (storm track and line)?
2. How can I make code in Matlab that calculates the angle between the storm track and lines that are overlapped?
   I already tried but it’s not working.

   ```
   N = 50; % Number of events  
   X = 50; Y = 50; 

   P1x = rand(N,1) * X;
   P1y = rand(N,1) * Y ; % initial point

   L = lognrnd(2,0.7,[N,1]); % Sample track length 
   Theta = mod(normrnd(90,15,[N,1]),360);

   dx = L.*cos(deg2rad(Theta - 90)); 
   dy = L.*sin(deg2rad(Theta - 270));

   P2x = P1x + dx; P2y = P1y + dy; % Final point

   plot([0 X X 0 0],[0 0 Y Y 0]); hold on

   for j = 1:N
       plot(P1x(j),P1y(j),'ro')
       plot([P1x(j) P2x(j)],[P1y(j) P2y(j)],'-') 
   end

   k=line([(X+Y)/2.25, (X+Y)/3, (X+Y)/3, (X+Y)/4] , [0, (X+Y)/10, (X+Y)/2.5, (X+Y)/2]);

   xlabel('X [km]'); ylabel('Y [km]');
   xlim([-X/4 1.25*X]); ylim([-Y/4 1.25*Y])
   ```

[image: plot screenshot]

Comment: There is no legend in your plot....why don't you tell us..what you want from figure? Is it the points (red circles) intersecting the blue box? Be clear. Specify what is a track and what is a line here?

Comment: here, i already generate 50 storm track randomly. (if you run this code then you might be understand). red circles are the initial point of the storm track which is passes from left to right direction towards the blue line and blue  line is the line structures (assumes).  i need to know how many storm track will pass this blue line (that means line structures) how many not  and also how many intersect? also if the storm track and line intersects each other then what is the angle between this two ? whole process  has to be made through Matlab? i hope you will understand now @SivaSrinivas

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function **[InterX](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22441-curve-intersections?focused=5165138&tab=function)** to get the intersection point between the blue line and the storm line. Check the below code. I have made few changes at the plot of storm line, you need not to use a loop there. Once you have the intersection point, you can get the required angle using *dot product* or *slope formula*.

```
N = 50; % Number of events
X = 50; Y = 50;

P1x = rand(N,1) * X;
P1y = rand(N,1) * Y ; % initial point

L = lognrnd(2,0.7,[N,1]); % Sample track length
Theta = mod(normrnd(90,15,[N,1]),360);

dx = L.*cos(deg2rad(Theta - 90));
dy = L.*sin(deg2rad(Theta - 270));

P2x = P1x + dx; P2y = P1y + dy; % Final point

plot([0 X X 0 0],[0 0 Y Y 0]); hold on
% GEt the line 
lx = [(X+Y)/2.25, (X+Y)/3, (X+Y)/3, (X+Y)/4] ;
ly = [0, (X+Y)/10, (X+Y)/2.5, (X+Y)/2];
plot(lx,ly,'b')

plot(P1x,P1y,'ro')
plot([P1x P2x]',[P1y P2y]','-')

% Get intersections 
iwant = zeros(N,1) ;  % this gives whether point intersects or not 
for i = 1:N
    L1 = [lx ; ly] ;
    L2 = [P1x(i) P2x(i) ;P1y(i) P2y(i)] ;
    P = InterX(L1,L2) ;
    if ~isempty(P)
        plot(P(1),P(2),'*r')
        iwant(i) = 1 ;
    end
end

xlabel('X [km]'); ylabel('Y [km]');
xlim([-X/4 1.25*X]); ylim([-Y/4 1.25*Y])
```

Check the figure/ result generated from the above code. The red starred points are your intersection points.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your response. i will check it . if i face some problem again i will ask you ..thank you once again :)

Comment: hi Siva Srinivas Kolukula, hope you are fine. i need some help again regarding MATLAB CODE. Now i want to make some foot print rectangle area around each of the storm track length. In details, each storm track length will be the central length of the rectangle. I need to make this code in previous code through Matlab. So would you please help me. I tried a lot but could not.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 50; % Number of events
X = 50; Y = 50;
P1x = rand(N,1) * X; P1y = rand(N,1) * Y ; % initial point
L = lognrnd(2,0.7,[N,1]); % Sample track length
Theta = mod(normrnd(90,15,[N,1]),360); % Storm track bearing direction
dx = L.*cos(deg2rad(Theta - 90)); dy = L.*sin(deg2rad(Theta - 270));
P2x = P1x + dx; P2y = P1y + dy; % Final point
plot([0 X X 0 0],[0 0 Y Y 0]); hold on
plot(P1x,P1y,'ro');
plot([P1x P2x]',[P1y P2y]','-')
xlabel('X [km]'); ylabel('Y [km]');
xlim([-X/4 1.25*X]); ylim([-Y/4 1.25*Y])
%% Draw rectangles
Vx = [P1x P2x]' ;
Vy = [P1y P2y]' ;
t = 1./2 ;
% Loop to get normals
for i = 1:size(Vx,2)
    N=LineNormals2D([Vx(:,i) Vy(:,i)]') ;

    C = [[Vx(:,i) Vy(:,i)]+t*N ;
        [Vx(:,i) Vy(:,i)]-t*N] ;
    idx = boundary(C(:,1),C(:,2)) ;
    plot(C(idx,1),C(idx,2),'b')
end
```

Down the LineNormals2D function from the link: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32696-2d-line-curvature-and-normals

Comment: Many thanks !!.. I will check it and if i face some problem again i will ask you ..thank you once again.. :)

Comment: I need your help again. with your help i already got randomly rectangle foot print area. But as you know there is also 1 blue line (please see attached image above). Now if the rectangle foot print intersect the blue line then how may i get the intersect point between rectangle foot print and line? Previously it was line to line intersect but now rectangle foot print to line intersect and i need to make some code and plot in matlab about this. For your kind notification you may check above the code file also @Siva Srinivas Kolukula .. many thanks and sorry to bother you.

Comment: @ Siva Srinivas Kolukula  i need your help. Please kindly help me if possible for you .thank you in advance and sorry to bother you.